# Calculate the midpoint of a polyline

Tags: geometry

I have a polyline in a mapping system:

[image]

The polyline is made of multiple vertices:

```
+----+----+
| x  | y  |
+----+----+
|  0 |  5 |
| 10 | 10 |
| 30 |  0 |
| 50 | 10 |
| 60 | 10 |
+----+----+
```

I would like to calculate the coordinates of the midpoint of the line.

How can I do this?

Comment: First step is To find the distance of the whole line using Pythagorean’s theorem.  Then find the midpoint distance by dividing that by two.  Then find out which line segment the midpoint is on and use Pythagorean’s theorem again.

Comment: First step is to find a piece of thread, and trace the whole line with that thread. Then find the midpoint distance by putting the two endpoints together and stretch the thread in the middle. Then cut the thread at the midpoint and use half of it to trace the line again.

Comment: This seems like a programming problem, as the midpoint of a segment mathematically is trivial. To get from a segment to a polyline it is no more challenging mathematically, but rather a question of bookkeeping programming-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to find the coordinate of a point that is a distance of $g$ from one of the endpoints of a line segment. The endpoints **A** and **B** have coordinates $(x_A,\,y_A)$ and $(x_B,\,y_B)$.

1. Find the length of the segment

   $$\ell = \sqrt{ (x_B-x_A)^2 + (y_B-y_A)^2 } \tag{1} $$
2. Find the direction vector from **A** towards **B** (unit magnitude)

   $$ \boldsymbol{\hat{e}} = \frac{ (x_B-x_A,\, y_B-y_A) }{\ell} \tag{2} $$
3. Find the coordinates of the desired point **P**, a distance $g$ from **A** along $\boldsymbol{\hat{e}}$

   $$ (x_P,\,y_P) = ( x_A + \tfrac{g}{\ell} (x_B-x_A), y_A + \tfrac{g}{\ell} (y_B-y_A) ) $$

Can you answer the question from here?

Take the total length of the polyline $L$ and find after which vertex the midpoint $L/2$ lies on, and by what margin $g$. Keep subtracting segment lengths from $L/2$ until the next segment contains the midpoint. The use the technique above to find the coordinates.